# Function from .dll fails from vb.net, but works from vb6

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a test device supplied by a third party. The device connects to a computer via an Ethernet port and is used to test automotive sensors in a production environment, the device was supplied with a .dll and .lib file.

When I call "connect_function" from the dll in vb.net, the function returns a negative number indicating that the connection to the device failed.

When I call the "connect-function" from the dll in vb6 or lib in C, the function returns a zero, indicating a successful connection.

I am not a 'programmer' exactly, although I wind up doing a lot of programming as a manufacturing engineer.  I am completely stumped at troubleshooting any further.  I have tried marshaling data until I'm blue in the face, but I don't think that is the issue, because the call succeeds, its just the dll doesn't connect.

So all that is to ask: What is different between the way vb6 and c++ make function calls vs. the way vb.net makes function calls?

---

Update: 8/22/2017:
Thanks for the replies! I have boiled down the code below.

In all cases  I am not getting any compiler errors, but only in vb.net does the dll return a negative.  I don't understand how the dll would know the difference.

Vb.net Code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module Module1
    <DllImport("myDevice.dll")> _
    Public Function CreateDeviceObject _
        (ByVal deviceType As Integer, _
         ByVal deviceNum As Integer, _
         ByVal deviceChan As Integer, _
         ByVal deviceName As String, _
         ByRef pointerToHandle As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
End Module

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myHandle As Integer
        MsgBox("CreateAPSxObject Returned: " & CreateDeviceObject(2, 1, 1, "yo", myHandle))
    End Sub
End Class
```

VB6 Code:

```
Private Declare Function CreateDeviceObject Lib "myDevice.dll" _
    (ByVal deviceType As Long, _
     ByVal deviceNum As Long, _
     ByVal deviceChan As Long, _
     ByVal deviceName As String, _
     ByRef pointerToHandle As Long) As Long

Public myHandle As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    MsgBox (CreateDeviceObject(2, 1, 1, "yo", myHandle))
End Sub
```

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int __stdcall CreateDeviceObject (int, int,int,char *,int *);

int main()
{
    int myError=0, myHandle;

    myError = CreateAPSxObject(2,1,1,"yo",&myHandle);
    printf("Return=%d: ",myError);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since your DLL works from VB6, it must be a COM DLL.  Are you treating it as such from your .NET code?

Comment: Have a look at this MSDN article:  [Calling COM Components from .NET Clients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx)

Comment: Is this a COM interface or a regular function exported from a DLL? That is, in VB6, do you have "Declare Function" to declare the function or do you import a reference?

Comment: @STLDeveloper - VB6 can call almost any DLL that uses stdcall, not just COM DLLs. That's what `Declare Function` is for.

Comment: @CurtisSmith : Can you show us the DLL's function declaration and your VB.NET version of it so that we can see and identify possible issues? The difference between VB6 and VB.NET in this case is mainly the data types.

Comment: Since you haven't shown us your code I can't say this is your problem for sure. Is the size of an integer, long changed in VB.net. An integer will be a short in .net and a long will be an integer.

Comment: @STLDeveloper :It is not a COM DLL. I am having to "Declare Function" or "DLLImport".

Comment: @VisualVincent: Thank you, I added my code to the original post.

Comment: @MarkHall: Thank you. I think I am declaring my data types correctly. int in C (4 bytes), Integer in vb.net, and Long in VB6.

Comment: Your last parameter is incorrect. Pointers are mostly mapped to `IntPtr`. A `ByRef ... Integer` is equivalent to `int &`. This is the correct declaration: `ByVal pointerToHandle As IntPtr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Visual Studio 2013 was configured to save my project files to the windows "My Documents" folder, which my IT department has re-routed onto the company network. The VB6 and C stuff was on my local disk (C:).

When I moved the vb.net (Visual Studio 2013) project folder to my local disk (C:\VB) the dll worked as it should.

Thanks to all that took the time review this topic.  I can't explain why that made a difference, but hopefully it will help someone in the future.